# Can Bumblee really help with Optimus Laptops?

Tags: ubuntu, power-management, nvidia

I bought Lenovo Z570 which comes with nVidia GEForce GT520M (Optimus technology) and recently I installed Ubuntu 11.10. Surprisingly, whenever I boot my system CPU fan rotates at very high speed and so my battery backup is screwed up.I googled about this problem but I am not able to come to some conclusion.

According to some vague sources, because of some bug, the Linux kernel is not able to support Optimus technology as of now. Does anyone have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those sources might be outdated, which is very common in the FOSS community.  Answer aping is also common, so outdated information can be spread years after its obsolescence.

I will say the support is still considered a WIP, but it does exist.  The project is called Bumblebee (its a play on optimus prime).  The best guide I've seen online is at the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bumblebee).

Comment: I Installed bumblebee but still I'm not able to use my graphics card..

Comment: @user997704 With Bumblebee you need to run `optirun [program name]` to render applications on the graphics card. When installing Bumblebee, you should immediately notice power savings because the nvidia card is not powered. See also [this Optimus question on AU](http://askubuntu.com/q/36930/6969)